Do non-Schengen EU countries check proof of funds?
For a US citizen born in the US, I know that Schengen ones do check, but I don't remember if all EU countries do. Do they?
What brought it to my attention again is that Serbia, Bulgaria and Romania have the same funds requirement of €50 per day, with Bosnia's even higher. Their amounts are higher than Schengen countries', so I'm wondering if their immigration officers ask questions differently.

Serbia and Bosnia are not in Schengen but aren't in the EU either. Bulgaria and Romania are in the EU, but are also in Schengen. But quite generally, I would be surprised if they checked in any systematic way, only if they have any doubts.

Bulgaria and Romania have their own stays and are not part of the 90-day in/out Schengen visa, they still have their own visas.

That's no longer the case since March 31st, Romania and Bulgaria are Schengen members nearly like any other (the only difference is that there are still border checks between Romania and Bulgaria and the rest of the Schengen countries at land borders). Visas are now the same, and the 90/180 count is now common with the rest of Schengen.

It's called the "Schengen air and maritime space " so I want to know if you need a Schengen visa if entering by land or if it you have to leave the Schengen area without a Schengen visa even if you enter by land.

Yes, you need Schengen visa if entering by land.

The fact that you enter by land or by air does not change the fact that you would use the same visa for Bulgaria, Romania or the rest of the Schengen Area, and in your case (a US citizen) you would not need a visa any more than for the rest of Schengen. They are now Schengen countries like any other in terms of visas and 90/180 rule. The only difference is that there are still systematic checks at the land borders between them and the rest of Schengen.

Depending on accommodation arrangements, the limits you mention are not higher than all  Schengen countries. For example, France is €65, Netherlands is €55, and Poland is €62, while Italy has a sliding scale depending on the number of days/visitors.
